Can two predicates be necessarily extensionally equivalent, but have different intensions?
If two predicates P1 an P2 have the same extension across every possible world, i.e they always pick out the same objects, does that mean that their intension is the same? For example "brother" and "male cousin" have the same intension, and in every world where something is a brother, that thing is a male cousin.
I know the classical counterexample of "is a creature with a heart" and "is a creature with a kidney", and that extensional equivalence doesn't translate that well into intensional equivalence. But in this example I'd say that this is only because it isn't a necessary extensional equivalence. There is a possible world where some creature has a heart but no kidney, and this is why their intension is different. In fact, if two predicates having the same extension across all possible worlds isn't enough to guarantee having the same intention, I really don't know what could be, and I would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me if my intuition is wrong.

Any two different predicative phrases or terms  can be seen as having different intensions -- if it's given that their "conceptual content" or "sense" differs from each other. You don't need to invoke the philosophical fiction of "possible worlds" for this.

@mudskipper Is what I said false though? I would rather understand it through their extension if possible rather than some "conceptual content" that is quite more mysterious to me and more difficult to work with.

You are relying on some concept of "possible world". It's unclear to me what that means,  so, I cannot tell if what you said is false. I guess you could stipulate it to be true and say - that is how I understand "possible world"...

If you are using possible world semantics, then it is standard to account for intensionality in terms of what is coextensive in all possible worlds. So your example is correct. "Has a heart" and "has kidneys" have different intensions and while they are extensionally equivalent at the actual world they are not extensionally equivalent across all possible worlds.
There is also the concept of hyperintensionality for concepts that are necessarily coextensive but still have different meanings.
There are different ways of accounting for intensionality. If you prefer not to use possible worlds, you can think instead in terms of substitutivity. Two predicates that share the same extension can be substituted in extensional contexts within a sentence without changing the truth value of the sentence. (This is sometimes called substitution salva veritate by people who like to show off their Latin.) Two predicates that share the same intension can be substituted salva veritate in intensional contexts such as those expressing necessity. Two predicates that differ hyperintensionally cannot be substituted salve veritate even in contexts that are necessarily equivalent.
The SEP article on hyperintensionality puts it like this:

A and B are necessarily equivalent when they are true at the same
worlds. This is sometimes put in terms of sentences sharing an
intension. An extensional operator (e.g., Boolean negation) allows
substitution salva veritate of sentences with the same extension,
that is, truth value: if A has the same truth value as B, then also ∼A
has the same truth value as ∼B. An intensional operator (e.g., the
box of necessity) allows substitution salva veritate of sentences
that express necessary equivalents: if A is necessarily equivalent to
B, then □A has the same truth value as □B. The expression
“hyperintensional” is thus for an H that defies substitution salva
veritate even of expressions with the same intension.


What you wrote answers the question, but doesn't actually say "yes" or "no" explicitly. To put a finer point on it: under the most standard understanding of intensions, the answer to the question in the title of the post is "no", while the answer to the question in the first sentence of the post is "yes."
